# Packaging WAR with Java and Scala sources

Tags: scala, jakarta-ee, maven-3, war, maven-plugin

I would like to ask you simple question. Is it possible to package WAR file which will contain Scala and Java sources, each from separate source directory (src/main/java/... and src/main/scala/...)? Of course, I still like to contain other resources like images and static pages into resulting WAR.

I've been looking into WAR plugin capabilities, regarding additional sources, but I didn't find anything helpful in this area. Can anyone give me a hint, where should I look for solution, or perhaps any kind of help?

Thanks,
Matthew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a cut down version of the pom I use for my multi-language projects.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sksamuel</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.33-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <maven.plugin.jar.version>2.4</maven.plugin.jar.version>
        <maven.plugin.war.version>2.3</maven.plugin.war.version>
        <maven.plugin.resources.version>2.6</maven.plugin.resources.version>
        <maven.plugin.compiler.version>3.1</maven.plugin.compiler.version>
        <maven.plugin.surefire.version>2.14.1</maven.plugin.surefire.version>
        <maven.plugin.dependency.version>2.4</maven.plugin.dependency.version>
        <maven.plugin.scala.version>3.1.5</maven.plugin.scala.version>

        <compiler.version.source>1.7</compiler.version.source>
        <compiler.version.target>1.7</compiler.version.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.plugin.war.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.plugin.scala.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-source</goal>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

After running mvn clean package inside that directory, with a scala source in src/main/scala and a java source file in src/main/java this is what I get. And as you can see the scala and java files have both been compiled into the war.

```
$ find .
.
./pom.xml
./target
./target/test
./target/test/WEB-INF
./target/test/WEB-INF/lib
./target/test/WEB-INF/lib/scala-library-2.10.2.jar
./target/test/WEB-INF/classes
./target/test/WEB-INF/classes/ILoveJava.class
./target/test/WEB-INF/classes/ILoveScala$.class
./target/test/WEB-INF/classes/ILoveScala.class
./target/test/WEB-INF/web.xml
./target/test/META-INF
./target/classes.-1172594870.timestamp
./target/maven-archiver
./target/maven-archiver/pom.properties
./target/test.war
./target/classes
./target/classes/ILoveJava.class
./target/classes/ILoveScala$.class
./target/classes/ILoveScala.class
./target/surefire
./src
./src/main
./src/main/webapp
./src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
./src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
./src/main/java
./src/main/java/ILoveJava.java
./src/main/scala
./src/main/scala/ilovescala.scala
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but it's not working for me. I tried same configuration of scala-maven-plugin as you have, but my java sources are not compiled and packaged into resulting WAR. Would you mind posting configuration of your WAS plugin? I think solution might be there.

Comment: Although that pom is a cut down from the "real one" I use day to day, I tested it before posting, and the file listing is the actual file listing after running mvn clean package. The .war file also contains the contents as it should.

Comment: I would suggest you make a setup like me, create 2 dummy files like I did - one scala source, one java source, and then use my pom on. Then work backwards to find out what in your setup breaks it.